# I need this object inside the map, but i cant get it

Tags: dart

I have this list of maps, and i need to get the 'transactions' value:

```
final assets = [
    {
    "name": "BRL", "balance": 150.2, 
    "transactions" : Transaction(from: "someone", amount: 1)
    },
    {
    "name": "US", "balance": 1100.2, 
    "transactions" : Transaction(from: "someone", amount: 5)
    },
  ];
```

i tried to do `assets[0]['transactions']`, but all i got was null or Instance of 'Transaction'

the class:

```
class Transaction {
  final String id = Random().toString();
  final String from;
  final double amount;

  Transaction({
    required this.from,
    required this.amount,
  });
  
}
```

im kinda newbie, then pls help me :)

Comment: You already got the value. It is just that your object does not implement any `toString()` method which means it uses the default implementation from `Object` which will just print `Instance of 'Transaction'`. You can try access one of the values of the `Transaction` object by doing: `print(assets[0]['transactions']?.amount);`

Comment: This error message appears when i try it:
`The property 'amount' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`
And when i correct it: 
`The getter 'amount' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'amount', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'amount'`
Though it doesnt make sense, since we can do it on the other example XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?70e4bb95ee6fc57ae111046d6830fff1) example to view this in an app

Assuming you would like to show your data in a list (since this is a list of maps per the question)

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: assets.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Transaction data = assets[index]['transactions'];
          return 
            ListTile(
              leading: Text(data.amount.toString()),
              title: Text(data.from.toString()));
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to set the variable Transaction data to 
var data = assets[index]['transactions'] as Transaction;
But it worked. Thank you!